# Django and Flask on same nginx server with gunicorn

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn, flask

I currently have a Djago app running on my main site when I visit mysite.com. However, I'd like mysite.com/flaskapp to run a separate Flask application. I'm able to set up two nginx site-enabled config files and run each app on a different port but, for various reasons, I'd like to run them all on the same port (if possible). When I configure my flaskapp/ location in my nginx server file I get a 404 error.

Here's my supervisor config file:

```
[program:MYSITE]
command=/var/www/html/MYSITE/prodenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/MYSITE.sock MYSITE.wsgi
directory=/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/MYSITE.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/MYSITE.out.log


[program:FLASKAPP]
directory=/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/FLASKAPP/api
command=/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/FLASKAPP/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/FLASKAPP/api/FLASKAPP.sock FLASKAPP:app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/FLASKAPP.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/FLASKAPP.out.log
```

And my nginx site-enabled file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name MYSITE;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
            root /var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html;
        expires 30d;
        }

    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/MYSITE.sock;
        }

    location /FLASKAPP/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/FLASKAPP/api/FLASKAPP.sock; 
        }


}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Check the ownership of the socket files, they need to be owned by your nginx user.

Comment: @SimonGreenwood I don't think that's the problem because if I split FLASKAPP into it's own nginx config, just with a different port, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I rewrote the url to remove the subdirectory and now it all works.

before:

```
    location /FLASKAPP/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/FLASKAPP/api/FLASKAPP.sock; 
    }
```

after:

```
location /FLASKAPP/ {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/FLASKAPP/api/FLASKAPP.sock; 
    rewrite ^/FLASKAPP(.*)$ $1 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is typo in proxy_path. You have `proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/FLASKAPP/api/FLASKAPP.sock;`, but there should be `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/FLASKAPP/api/FLASKAPP.sock;`. Remove `http://`, change `proxy_pass` to `fastcgi_pass` and everything should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. Removing the http:// wouldn't even allow me to restart my nginx service. I received a "Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server." error in the log.

Comment: @pnus sorry, there should be `fastcgi_pass` instead of `proxy_pass`.

Comment: Well, I'm not getting a 404 error like I was before but now it's just spinning it's wheels until it eventually gets a 502 error :-/